# Get path to original item of a file alias when it's missing

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to write a script to correct the path to an original item of a file alias. I know what's wrong with the path (I moved a folder), so if I can get what the system thinks the path is, I can fix it.

The problem is that the script simply reports that the original can't be found and not where the original **should** be.

Is there a way to grab that from with AppleScript? It's there in the Get Info... box, so it's stored in the file. I suspect I could use some bash way to get it with a `do shell script`, but I'm curious about staying within AS.

Comment: An alias file contains a few data items other than a path, but an alias is a dynamic link that should not be affected by just moving the file item - could you be talking about a symbolic link?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly of what the process was, but it definitely happens that aliases get separated from their originals.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "alias" ?  It has several meanings in macOS.  How was the alias file created initially ?

Comment: I mean the files that are called aliases in the Finder and file aliases in AppleScript.

Answer (score 0):

Years ago, I also had issue with my alias, when changing folders. This is part of the script I made which looks into Get Info window. Since, may be the Get Info window has been changed on last OS version, therefore, some adjustments are required, but it gives you the direction to go:

```
on Origine_Alias(F_Alias)
    set R to ""
    tell application "Finder" to open information window of file (F_Alias as text)
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Finder" to set R to value of static text 18 of scroll area 1 of front window
    tell application "Finder" to close front window
    return R
end Origine_Alias
```

The returned string is in Unix format: /folder/my/file

Comment: Works as is in **macOS High Sierra**, however, for **macOS Catalina** change `static text 18` to `static text 17`.